Law of large numbers for higher moment condition
Let $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean 0, unit variance, and finite absolute third moment. Define $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Then we know following hold:
(1) for $0<p<2$, $\frac{S_n}{n^{1/p}} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely, and
(2) (CLT) $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to standard normal.
My question is:
(i) Is it true that  "for $2<q\leq 3$, $\quad \frac{S_n}{n^{1/q}}~~$ can NEVER converge in distribution" ?
(ii) If yes, then how can we prove that? I tried making following argument
$\quad \quad $ let's assume $\frac{S_n}{n^{1/q}} \implies Z$, where $Z$ is some random variable. Then $Var(Z)\approx \frac{Var(S_n)}{n^{2/q}} = \frac{n}{n^{2/q}}$ which means that $Var(Z)$ grows to infinity, but this is not possible.
Is this a correct way of thinking about it?

$Var(Z_q)$ being infinite is not enough on its own as there are distributions with infinite variance.  You need something which in handwaving terms is that (2) tells you $Z_2$ is a standard normal so $Z_q$ is normal but with infinite variance and that is impossible.
